# Checking hasNextInt() in if and then receive an input

Tags: java, if-statement, input, java.util.scanner, user-input

So a simple program would be:

```
import java.util.*;
public class practice {
      static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      public static void main(String[] args) {

           if(reader.hasNextInt()){

               int numberEntered = reader.nextInt();
           }


      }

}
```

So I have a misunderstanding. `hasNextInt()` is supposed to check if the next input will be an *int* or not. I saw this program and I don't understand how the number can be inputed. Because already for getting an input the `reader.hasNextInt()` needs to be true and the program hasn't got an input. So how will the program get inside the if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Scanner#hasNextInt()`, in your case, is a `blocking method`. This means, it is a method which waits and does only return if some conditions are met. It looks something like this:

```
public boolean hasNextInt() {
    ...
    boolean condition = false;
    while(!condition) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    return stuff;
}
```

To be more precise, the blocking method is `Scanner#hasNext()`. It is described in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()).
If the method blocks or not depends on the `Scanner`s source. If it is, for example `System.in`, it will wait. If it is just a `File`, it will read the whole file until its end and then return, no blocking.

So, what happens? The `hasNextInt` in your `if-condition` waits for you to enter some input (until you send it by typing `Enter`). Then the `Scanner` saves the input inside a buffer. `hasNextInt` checks the internal buffer but does not delete stuff from the buffer.

Now comes `nextInt` which reads from the internal buffer and also deletes the stuff inside it. It *advances past read input*.

You can read it in detail inside the documentation mentioned above.

**Things short**: `Scanner#hasNextInt()` waits for input before it returns `true` or `false`.